# How to delete object from array of objects in array of objects javascript by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, array-splice

How to remove an object by index from array of objects in array of objects.

I want to remove the first object from the array with a variable value in the object id "A1"

```
let data =
[ 
  { id: 'A1',
    value:  [ { uri: 'B45AA03A05B7.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' },
              { uri: '30A42FBC1146.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' } ] 
  },
  { id: 'A2',
    value:  [ { uri: 'G455HFG2FF56.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' },
              { uri: 'TY6DFG7RTGF.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' } ] 
  }
]
```

required output

```
let data =
[ 
  { id: 'A1',
    value:  [ { uri: '30A42FBC1146.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' } ] 
  },
  { id: 'A2',
    value:  [ { uri: 'G455HFG2FF56.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' },
              { uri: 'TY6DFG7RTGF.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' } ] 
  }
]
```

i tried this

```
const array1 = data.filter((item) => item.id == deleteId)

   if (delIndex > -1) {
     array1[0].value.splice(delIndex, 1);
   }
```

Comment: yes, that's how you'd do it ... if `delIndex` is 0, it deletes the first, and 1 deletes the second ... how is `delIndex` set?

Comment: This should work if deleteId and delIndex are correctly set.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as [tag:react-native]? Are you using `data` or `array1` in a state? If so you probably don't want to use `splice()` since a state should not be mutated, only re-assigned.

Comment: sorry, but what is even the question? What is the problem? "I tried this ..." OK, code looks good to me -> question solved? Otherwise please explain what problem you have. What is **not working**? And maybe *how is it not working*? How does the result that you get differ from the result you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the object and delte the first object of `value`.

```js
let data = [{ id: 'A1', value: [{ uri: 'B45AA03A05B7.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' }, { uri: '30A42FBC1146.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' }] }, { id: 'A2', value: [{ uri: 'G455HFG2FF56.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' }, { uri: 'TY6DFG7RTGF.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' }] }],
    deleteId = 'A1',
    object = data.find(({ id }) => id == deleteId);

if (object) object.value.splice(0, 1);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
data.reduce((prev,curr) => {
  if (curr.id === "A1") {
    curr.value.shift()
  }
  return [...prev, curr]
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works!

```
// ?. this is optional chaining for javascript operator

data.find(item => item.id === 'A1')?.value.shift();
```